# How do I embed a Preact website into existing website?

Tags: preact

I've created a Preact website: https://alwaysselector-2d06f.firebaseapp.com/ , and another website allows me to upload content within their 'contentDiv'.

```
<div id="contentDiv">
 //what should I put here?
</div>
```

My question is I don't know what to put inside the div. I don't want to use an iFrame because in some cases my external website height can vary. Therefore,

```
<iframe src='https://alwaysselector-2d06f.firebaseapp.com/' />
```

will not work. What's the most simple way to get all of the html from my external website to load within contentDiv?

Answer (score 0):

Existing Application HTML

```
<div id="someOtherApp">
   <h1>
     Some other app
   </h1>
   <div id="addYourPreactApp">
       <h1>Add Preact app hook here</h1>
       <div id="preactAppRoot"> 
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Now you can hook your preact application into html element( div#preactAppRoot ).

```
/** @jsx h */
const { h, render, Component } = preact;    // normally this would be an import statement.

class Clock extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        // set initial time:
        this.state.time = Date.now();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // update time every second
        this.timer = setInterval(() => {
            this.setState({ time: Date.now() });
        }, 1000);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        // stop when not renderable
        clearInterval(this.timer);
    }

    render(props, state) {
        let time = new Date(state.time).toLocaleTimeString();
        return <span>{ time }</span>;
    }
}

// render an instance of Clock into <body>:
render(<Clock />, document.getElementById("preactAppRoot"));
```

Working example can be found on jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/cte27dhw/

Comment: Thanks front_end_dev, almost there but assume the preact application was hosted elsewhere and I couldn't add the entire preact app (imagine it's 100,000 lines and too big) in the other existing application. How could I import the preact app, and then load the preact app to the existing html application.

Do I use a script tag to import my preact app and then something like 'window.parent.document.getElementById' within my preact app?

Comment: @Will - I hope you are generate a production bundle of preact application. You just have to add that script into third party html file where you want to add your preact app. Please look into the updated jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/uL897c1t/1/

Comment: thanks @front_end_dev ... how would I load that js? 

div id="someOtherApp">
   <h1>
     Some other app
   </h1>
   <div id="addYourPreactApp">
       <h1>Add Preact app hook here</h1>
       <div id="preactAppRoot"> 
//WHAT DO I PUT HERE, something like this script?
<script defer="defer" src="https//app.com/bundle.7afa9.js"></script>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>

Comment: @Will You don't have to put anything here. Hook to attach preact code is done using  `render` function. Look this [Without_Uglify_Fiddle]( https://jsfiddle.net/cte27dhw/) the last line is `render(<Clock />, document.getElementById("preactAppRoot"));`. Here preact code is attached on element with id preactAppRoot. 3rd party html only need to add a div element ( #preactAppRoot ) and bundle attached code into that element.  [Fiddle_With_Uglify_That_is_Your_Bundle_Also](http://jsfiddle.net/uL897c1t/1/) . If you still wondering how it's working then i can create a github gist and share with you.